# Azure function in python 3.8 in Linux failing when invoking Azure ML

Tags: python, linux, azure, function, azure-machine-learning-service

I am working on an Azure Function which is written in Python 3.8. Azure function in Azure in Python is deployed in Linux. The Azure function is invoking Azure ML pipeline. When invoking the pipeline I am seeing the following exception:

Exception: NotImplementedError: Linux distribution debian 11. does not have automatic support.
.NET Core 2.1 can still be used via dotnetcore2 if the required dependencies are installed.
Visit https://aka.ms/dotnet-install-linux for Linux distro specific .NET Core install instructions.
Follow your distro specific instructions to install `dotnet-runtime-*` and replace `*` with `2.1`

I have tried installing dotnetcore2 runtime via requirements.txt file but still getting the error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

---

> I am working on an Azure Function which is written in Python 3.8.
> Azure function in Azure in Python is deployed in Linux.

---

Based on the [***`Microsoft Documentation for Linux`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux) :-

The dot net core 2 version is not supported . Please try to install 3.12 or above to make it work.

I haven't tested in my environment.
[image]

For more information please refer the below links:-

- [***GitHub|dotnet-runtime-2.1 installed on Arch (GNU/Linux), but no support?***](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/1391#issuecomment-812056578)
- [***MS Q&A |AzureML Error on Linux: "Unable to retrieve .NET dependencies***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/361522/azureml-error-on-linux-34unable-to-retrieve-net-de.html)